# How to draw two plots in one Figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have two different diagrams. One of them consists of 3 plots and the other has only one. I want to put 3 plots in one diagram and the other one in another, but I don't know how.

For example:

- 3 plots are in diagram A: `y=x`, `y=2x-1`, and `y=3x**2+2x-1` for `x` in `(0,5)`
- 1 plot is in diagram B: `y=sin(3*pi/x)` for `x` in `(-0.5,0.5)`

In this case, when I use `plt.plot`, I get 4 plots in one diagram, which is not what I want.

So, I want a figure in which on the left side is diagram A and on the right side is diagram B, as shown in the drawing below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `plt.subplots` function to get handles on the axes, and plot from the `.plot` method of those axes:

```py
# -- Imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# -- Data
x1 = np.linspace(0, 5)

y11 = x1
y12 = 2 * x1 - 1
y13 = 3 * x1**2 + 3 * x1 - 1

x2 = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, num=500)
y2 = np.sin(3 * np.pi / x2)

# -- Plots
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

ax1.plot(x1, y11)
ax1.plot(x1, y12)
ax1.plot(x1, y13)
ax2.plot(x2, y2)

plt.show()
```

[image: plots]